# How to get network connection type in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell script I need to run some commands if the network connection type is not "DomainAuthenticated".

The aim is not to change the connection type manually, but run a set of commands.

I found about `Get-NetConnectionProfile`, but I can't find how to parse its output :

```
Name             : MyName
InterfaceAlias   : vEthernet (Port1)
InterfaceIndex   : 19
NetworkCategory  : DomainAuthenticated
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

I need to get the type from the line `NetworkCategory` so I can test its content and run my commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an individual property value from a powershell object a few ways, but the simplest is to pipe the output to the `Select` cmdlet:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select -ExpandProperty NetworkCategory
Private
Public
```

I have two entries because I have two network adapters. It entirely depends what you want to do with the output, but something like this might help:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select -ExpandProperty NetworkCategory | %{ if($_ -eq "DomainAuthenticated") { Write-Host "Replace Write-Host with what you want to do" } }
```

`%` is short-hand for "for each". `Select` is short-hand for `Select-Object`.

That's an example of both functional and procedural style scripting in Powershell. You may be able to pipe the output directly to another cmdlet though, and ignore the short-hand - it really does depend what your use-case is.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you put Get-NetConnectionProfile into a variable, you can just call $variable.NetworkCategory.  Like this :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ncp = Get-NetConnectionProfile
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ncp.NetworkCategory
DomainAuthenticated
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that if $ncp has more than one entry, $ncp.NetworkCategory will enumerate all the names at once.